# MVC passing object or string onclick function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc

Hi it just a simple problem but why i couldn't make it idk. I jut want to send this object onclick then render the sent data in modal. I can open modal onclick but when i try to pass object it gives error. also i splitted up this object and sent again now it gives this error

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list


 @foreach (var item in Model.Data)
 {
....
@{
var data1= item.Text;
var data2= item.TData;
data1= (data1== null) ? "" : data1.ToString();
data2= (data2== null) ? "" : data2.ToString();

}    
<div onclick="showdata(@data1,@data2)">@item.Text</div>
//it gives this error
    SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
function showdata(data1,data2) {
    console.log("shwdata data1");
    console.log(data1);
    console.log(data2); 
    $('#showTData').modal('show')

}
```

also I tryed

```
<div onclick="showdata(@item)">@item.Text</div>

function showdata(data) {
    console.log("shwdata data");
    console.log(data); 
    $('#showTData').modal('show')

}
//(index):377 Uncaught ReferenceError: XXXX is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick
```

Is there anyway to send object onlick. item is entity comes from list dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add `` like below:

```
<div onclick="showdata(`@data1`,`@data2`)">@item.Text</div>
```

Comment: it works fine in data1 but in data 2 it gives error. Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token. they both string

Comment: You need to check which line makes error.Check the console panel if all the two data have value.Then check which line makes such error.More detailed code would be helpful.

Comment: I changed ' to ` nad now it works, It's a bit interesting

Comment: Ok.I have updated the answer.You could accept the answer to let others find the solution quickly.